# jQuery Drop Down Menu Image Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been given a drop down menu to alter. I have been given this in the html portion:

```
<h1>Configure Your GT Super Sportscar</h1>
<form id = "sport" action="">
<table width = "35%" border = "2">
<tr><th colspan = "2">Choose a Colour</th></tr>
<tr><td>
<select id = "Colour" size = "5">
<option value='0'>Black</option>
<option value='1'>Blue</option>
<option value='2'>Red</option>
<option selected="selected" value='3'>Silver</option>
<option value='4'>White</option>
</select></td>
<td><img id = "carimage" src="images/silver.jpg" alt="Car model" ></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

And I have been given 5 different pictures of a car in different colors:

```
•   images/black.jpg
•   images/blue.jpg 
•   images/red.jpg 
•   images/silver.jpg 
•   images/white.jpg
```

When I click on the option red in the dropdown menu the picture or color of the car needs to change and I have no idea how to do it.

Please Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this one:

```
$('#Colour option').click(function(){
    $('#carimage').attr('src','images/' + $(this).text().toLowerCase() + '.jpg');
})
```

Comment: It would be better to use `.change()` so you don't have to worry about whether the mouse or the keyboard is used to make a selection

Comment: I have an experience before where using `change()` on a selected option doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Well it doesn't fire on the option, it does on the select. I don't recall seeing just "not work". Could you elaborate on that point?